# Does anyone know a way to play a video file with two its audio streams being simultaneously streamed to different output devices?

Tags: audio, video

I would like to know if it is possible to listen to one audio stream via the audio-jack speakers and to the other via the usb headset (that would just give me an ability to watch movies in English together with my wife watching it translated).

Thanks in advance.

P.S. If there seems to be no solution that would look like a nice programming task :)

Comment: Wow! Sounds like something for Paramount Pictures!

Comment: I wish it really would _sound_ :))

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have problems because the operating system will only stream to one sound device at a time - at least thinking of Windows or OS X. The problem is that you can only select one, right?

The only solution I could think of would be a sound interface with a routable mixer, things that are used in professional recording studios. I have a Saffire sound card that can produce different mixes for different headphones, but you need a Software that supports this, too, of course.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the direction/hint, so you think, this could not be an option in some geeky cccp/kgb player/player module?

Comment: Well if there is an application where you can specifically select the output device, then it might actually be possible. Winamp used to do this. But I still don't know if it's possible that the OS streams to two different sound cards at a time even if it were possible to select them, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Isn't that the application that kindof 'opens' audio devices (like it is with network interfaces) and then streams to them (I'm not sure)?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much so. But in the end it comes down to the OS, if it can "open" two devices at the same time. You might just try to get hold of a cheap second sound card, pop it in, and try to run for example two instances of Winamp, each with a different output device assigned. I'm really not too sure if that will work, however.